# Choosing right features for OCR of digits

Tags: java, opencv, computer-vision, ocr, feature-extraction

I have been working on doing some OCR for digits I take pictures of. Below is an example image:
[image]

I am implementing this application in Java with OpenCV. My first approach was to calculate the pixel values after resizing to 20x20 and use the Knn-algorithm to find the best match. This worked well sometimes, but I still had a bad success rate. I have been wondering if dividing each image into four quadrants and doing pixel calculation for the quadrants might improve the results.

I have tried to calculate hu invariant moments for each image. But it seems to me that these values are too similar, and not good enough for distinguishing each picture. It may be that I have been doing something wrong, but I have tried to calculate these moments from the contour as well as the image itself.

I was hoping someone was able to think of a good feature to use by looking at my picture. I have tried tesseract, but with not as good results I was hoping to get.

Comment: don't take one feature alone, better concat several short ones, like hu-moments, horizontal/vertical projections, 4x4pixel downsampled image, chain-codes, - play with it ! also 'patching' it into several subregions seems to be a good idea

Comment: Okay. Thanks :) i'll guess I have to dig a little deeper into it then

Comment: also there's more ml ideas than knn, svm seems to be anyone's darling for this

Comment: ok, I see. But my problem is really that I need something more exact than just the pixel values. I really hoped the hu moments would make a difference, but I find it really hard to use that as a good feature in this case based on the results I have

Comment: Did you try shape-context ?

Comment: @SemihKorkmaz no, I did not. I have tried the matchShapes()-function in opencv though, that basically returns a value based on the hu moments.